# model convert field automatically?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Who can I have a model which can save date in database in Greogorian but get and show in Jalali.
The jdatetime is very good but django_jalali which uses jdatetime for django is not a cool one and has poor documentation. so I just want to use jdatetime.

with jdatetime I can convert dates.

```
from jdatetime import date as jdate
from datetime import date
#get jalali date from gregorian
jd = jdate.fromgregorian(date=date.today())
#get gregorian date from jalali
gd = jd.togregorian()
```

I should get dates in Forms. using commit=False is good Idea but what if I use FormModel?

converting to jalali is done by template tag:

```
from jdatetime import date as jdate
def tojalali(value, arg=None):
    d = jdate.fromgregorian(date=value)
    return str(d.year) + '/' + str(d.month) + '/' + str(d.day)

register.filter('tojalali',tojalali)
```

How can I get date in jalali in Form and Convert it for model using ModelForm?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the standard Django Date Widget, and override the **format_value**(for retrieving gregorian from DB and showing jalali.) and **get_value_from_data_dict** methods.

Something like

```
class CategoryWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self,attrs=None):
        super(CategoryWidget, self).__init__(attrs)
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        #Your Code to process from jalali to gregorian.

   def format_value(self, value):
        #Your Code to process from gregorian to jalali.
```

[Detailed Tutorial](http://www.shauryac.com/index.php/2016/10/07/how-to-write-a-custom-field-widget-in-django/)
[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget)

I would suggest you to write a widget along with **render method** as well, since jalali calendar would be different and you would need a different calendar widget. Then override the two methods.
You can then specify which widget to use on the model form for that field.